# Pure TypeScript npm package

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create and use a 100% TypeScript npm package without building to JavaScript?

I tried so and added `"main": "index.ts"` into package.json but when I import my modules I get:

```
export * from './lib/my-module';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

The reason why I don't want to compile is that it is a private package and will be used in TypeScript projects only. Also I want to keep all decorators and comments as they are but when I tsc they get removed.

Comment: I'd imagine you distribute the package as a JS package and keep the source code as Typescript. What would be the point in preserving comments in a distributed package? You can also release your package with type definitions while still only distributing a compiled js package. Look at what angular does.

Comment: My instinct is “no” but perhaps it’s possible with the right tsconfig settings.

Comment: @marcusshep Where is the point building to JS when it is used in TS projects only? Btw. Angular is also keeping the comments so you see the docs when just clicking into a function/module/class, very handy!

Comment: your TS project using your TS library is still using the library in its JS compiled form. It's using the `.d.ts` files for typechecking, but the corresponding `.js` is what is executed. The only thing you'd be doing by not pre-compiling it is increasing the compile time of the end user. The files you're clicking into in angular are the `.d.ts` files, which you can generate with `declaration: true` in `compilerOptions` of tsconfig.json of your TS library. The comments being preserved are docstrings, not simple comments.

Comment: Still makes no sense to me compiling something and creating d.ts files that are not needed. Maybe we should move to Deno.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to create a pure typescript package.

1. In package you need to add `"main": "index.ts"`. `index.ts` should contain all types/components that should be available outside. For example:

```
export * from './model'
export * from './data-table'
export * from './context'
export * from './external-kit'
```

2. Exclude your package from `source-map-loader` in webpack.config.js

```
{
  enforce: 'pre',
  exclude: /PACKAGE_NAME/,
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|css)$/,
  loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
}
```

3. Add the path to your package in the loader, which is responsible for transpiling TS to JS. For me, this is babel-loader:

```
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  include: [paths.appSrc, path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/PACKAGE_NAME')],
  loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why should I use Webpack when I want a pure TS package? The package should be published as TypeScript files and consumed in TypeScript projects only. This does not seem to be possible in Node, I switch to Dino which has TypeScript built in.

Comment: Mick, I described the solution to the problem using my own example. You don't need to use webpack. The bottom line is that by default, the loader that is responsible for translating TS to JS (e.g. babel-loader) expects JS files in node_modules.

**Therefore, if you use TS package, you need to tell your loader the path to this package so that it knows about it.**

Comment: But my question was all about NOT transpiling TS to JS and instead of staying with TypeScript at all times.

Comment: @Mick Then your question is invalid, since for as long as there’s no runtime that executes TypeScript (as of 2023 there isn’t) you can’t stay with TypeScript “at all times”. This answer is correct in that NPM doesn’t care what you publish, JS or TS. It goes the extra mile to inform you how to correctly use this TS-only package in a project that inevitably runs JS (and the error you get is due to misconfigured transpilation/bundling). A typical project uses Webpack and Babel for that purpose, but if you have a more niche setup (like Deno or Bun) you could ignore that part of the answer.

Comment: How can a question be invalid? So the answer is "no, its not possible". This answer here says clearly "yes, it is possible" even tho it isnt.

Comment: @Mick The question was “how to publish a pure TypeScript published package on NPM without transpiling it to JavaScript”. *That* is perfectly possible, and this answer describes that. The answer additionally describes a way of transpiling TypeScript from that package to JavaScript in any real project, which is *required* if there is no runtime consumes TypeScript packages directly. But you in a comment amend the question to mean “publish a pure TypeScript package on NPM and never ever transpile it”.

Comment: That makes no sense because 1) it is not really in scope if you are talking about publication of a package: you *can* publish a TS package on NPM, and if there is a TS runtime in future then *it can just use this package*, the answer is perfectly correct here; and 2) until there is such a runtime, users of the package *will* need to transpile, and the answer gives an example of how it could be configured. Any angle I look at it, the answer seems correct and if you want to make the answer incorrect then I can’t see how the question would be valid.